# How to send message to a parentViewController that is a subclass of UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController (MyViewController) and another view controller i'm presenting modally though MyViewController (call it SecondViewController).  I want to be able to send a message to MyViewController from SecondViewController by using

```
[self.parentViewController hideSecondViewController];
```

But since parentViewController is defined as a UIViewController, and hideSecondViewController isn't a method of UIViewController, I get a warning saying "UIViewController may not respond to 'hideSecondViewController'".  It works fine, because it CAN send the message successfully during the program, but since I #import SecondViewController in MyViewController, I can't #import MyViewController in SecondViewController.  Any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When it comes time to dismiss a modal
>   view controller, the preferred
>   approach is to let the parent view
>   controller do the dismissing. In other
>   words, the same view controller that
>   presented the modal view controller
>   should also take responsibility for
>   dismissing it whenever possible.
>   Although there are several techniques
>   for notifying a parent view controller
>   that it should dismiss its modally
>   presented child, the preferred
>   technique is **delegation**.
>
> In a delegate-based model, the view
>   controller being presented modally
>   must define a **protocol** for its
>   delegate to implement. The protocol
>   defines methods that are called by the
>   modal view controller in response to
>   specific actions, such as taps in a
>   Done button. The delegate is then
>   responsible for implementing these
>   methods and providing an appropriate
>   response. In the case of a parent view
>   controller acting as a delegate for
>   its modal child, the response would
>   include dismissing the child view
>   controller when appropriate.

Read more at the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14).

---

P.S:

> since I #import SecondViewController
>   in MyViewController, I can't #import
>   MyViewController in
>   SecondViewController.

To solve a circular dependency problem you can use a [forward declaration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF124).

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to redesign your architecture as albertamg proposed but this should work:

> [self
>   dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

you can call dismiss on both the presenting and presented view controller and it will do the same thing.